# Is it possible to make an onfocus-function for the DataTable search bar in R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app that uses a DataTable. I want to create keyboard shortcuts for different elements in this app, which I can. However these shortcuts should only be triggered if the user has the search-bar blurred out. Expressed in another way: The shortcuts should not activate if the build in search-bar is focused.

I tried with the code below which works for a standard input-field. For some reason the DataTable search is not counted as a input-field as it does not react to the js-code. Does anyone know of a way to make a focus/blur check (onfocus or onblur events) for the DataTable searchbar?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$script('$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {Shiny.onInputChange("keytyped", [e.which,e.timeStamp]);});'),
  tags$script('$(document).ready(function() {

                $("input").on("focus", function(){
                  Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 1);
                });

                $("input").on("blur", function(){
                  Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 0);
                });
              });'),
  DT::dataTableOutput("datdata"),
  textInput("test", "Test:")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$datdata <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars
  ## THIS CALLBACK ONLY DOES SOMETHING WHEN SEARCHING! I NEED IT TO DO SOMETHING ON FOCUS!
  #                                      , callback = JS(
  #                                                      'table.on("search.dt", function(){
  #                                                        Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 1);
  #                                                      })'
  #                                                    )
  )

  observe({
    req(input$keytyped)
    req(is.null(input$foc) | !input$foc)

    ## (Big letter codes) R = 82, S = 83, T = 84
    check <- round(input$keytyped[1]) %in% c(82,83,84)

    if(check){
      print("ACTIVATE!")
    }

  })


  # Print DataTable search and if input-fields are focussed.
  observe(print(input$datdata_search))
  observe(print(input$foc))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I know above code is not bullet proof (Typing "R" then clicking anywhere else but the test-field 'activates' the shortcut), but I just wanted to provide a small example.

TLDR; Is it possible to make the app print 1 or 0 depending on whether the search bar from DataTable is focused or not.

**EDIT:** SmokeyShakers did what I asked for. But an addition I needed was that it should ONLY be on the search-bar the value should change. Removing

```
tags$script('$(document).ready(function() {

                $("#test").on("focus", function(){
                  Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 1);
                });

                $("#test").on("blur", function(){
                  Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 0);
                });
              });')
```

and then replacing "input" with "#datdata input" in the solution code solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htmlwidgets::onRender` can solve this issue. Try this for your datatable:

```
  output$datdata <- DT::renderDataTable(
    htmlwidgets::onRender(
        DT::datatable(mtcars), jsCode = HTML('function() {
            $("input").on("focus", function(){
                Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 1);
            });

           $("input").on("blur", function(){
               Shiny.onInputChange("foc", 0);
            });
         }')))
```